# Passing Textbox value to Crystal Report textbox

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Hello everyone I have a problem passing my textbox value into the textbox object in the crystal report.

so far these are the following codes that I have tried:

```
     TextObject yr = (TextObject)cy.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section1"].ReportObjects["gender1"];
     yr.Text = txtGender.Text;
```

It prompts with an error message saying: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
     cy.SetParameterValue("gender1", txtGender.text);
```

This one prompts: Invalid Index

This is my code for loading the records. Everything works except passing the value of the textbox.

Legend:

dt1 = Dataset

crpt.rpt = Crystal Report File

```
            SqlConnection conn = conString.getCon();
            ReportDocument cy = new ReportDocument();

            conn.Open();
            cy.Load(Application.StartupPath + @"\crpt.rpt");

            TextObject gr = (TextObject)cy.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section1"].ReportObjects["gender1"];
            gr.Text = txtGender.Text;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("exec viewInfo @gen", conn);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gen", txtGender.Text);

            dt1 ds = new dt1();
            da.Fill(ds.Info);
            cy.SetDataSource(ds);

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cy;
            conn.Close();
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set a parameter in the report, you can use

```
crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo["gender1"].CurrentValues.Add(txtGender.Text)
```

...*after* setting the `CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource`, though if you're getting that error, maybe you have a typo in the parameter name or the parameter wasn't created in the report file (.rpt) in the first place.

You could also look into `ReportDocument.RecordSelectionFormula` if you're trying to use `txtGender.Text` to filter data.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your first suggestion it prompts with this error message "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values" after the 'CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource'. I did make sure that I have the parameter name correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
CrystalReport2 objRpt = new CrystalReport2();

TextObject accntCode = (TextObject)objRpt.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section2"].ReportObjects["codeText11"];
accntCode.Text = codevalue;
```

Just use this, you don't need to use report document. You can directly assign values to the field object in your Crystal Report.

Answer (score -1):

The following should work for you:

```
TextObject text =(TextObject)CrystalReport21.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section3"].ReportObjects["Text19"];
            text.Text = comboBox2.Text;
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = name your crystalreport;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```